# getCenterLonLat differs from init values

Tags: openlayers-2

```
bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(36,57));

console.log(bounds.getCenterLonLat());
```

I expect something  like  `Object { lon=36, lat=57, ... }`

I get some Object with a different value for `lon`.

What can I do?

---

Question still open.

Comment: The code above works fine for me, so I can only guess. Do you use a projection transformation that could change the input coordinates?

Comment: Yes, the values are only examples. I use  `projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466")`. I just want to center my map at the given bounds and dont want these to get changed by the Projection (what ever it does).